# Index length for city name field

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design

I have a table with about 1000 cities. Sometimes, I need to search by city name and have therefore decided to make it an index. What would be the best practice to decide on the index length? 6 seems like the optimal choice, because there would be almost no duplicates.

**Example Table:**

```
cityID  |  cityName         |  countyID
     1  |  Bethlehem        |     30
     2  |  Blairstown       |     38
     3  |  Bloomfield       |     32
     4  |  Bloomingdale     |     34
     5  |  Bloomsbury       |     30
     6  |  Bogota           |     31
     7  |  Boonton          |     33
     8  |  Botsford         |     44
     9  |  Bound Brook      |     35
    10  |  Branchburg       |     35
    11  |  Branchville      |     36
    12  |  Brantwood        |     32
    13  |  Briarcliff Manor |     25
```

**cityID** - Primary Key

**countyID** - Key

**cityName (6)** - Key

Am I doing this right?

When I tried running

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM  'CITIES' 
WHERE  'cityName' =  'Branchburg'
```

I got the following results:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: CITIES
type: ref
possible_keys: cityName
key: cityName
key_len: 20
ref: const
rows: 2
Extra: Using where
```

Shouldn't "key_len" be 6?

Comment: What is the charset of the column? Is it UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on character set. For example, if you are using utf8, it is like 6 * 3 = 18 ... thought, I'm not sure where 2 bytes came from

Comment: Sorry to sound like a n00b, but is character set the same as collation? The columns collation is "utf8_unicode_ci".

Comment: Take a look here for differences between a character set and collation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html and to find out your character set, look here: https://wincent.com/wiki/Finding_out_the_encoding_of_a_MySQL_database

Comment: Thank you! Looks like its utf8. Does this somehow explain the extra 2 bytes? Also, am I understanding correctly how indexes work in terms of shortening it based on possible duplicates? Is this best practice?

Comment: Yes. Actually, you can make index shorter, but in that case, it will mean that db engine will do a bit of scanning. If you want to be sure, just don't specify index length...table of 1000 rows is quite small table, I don't think that you will notice a difference in speed or index size, no matter what you put for index length.

Comment: Thanks @vucetica, I understand that in this particular case the difference will not be noticeable, but I'm trying to learn best practices for future projects.